# How to get params from AuthorizationHandler .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am using an authorization handler to put custom authorization in my controller in .net core. How can I get the parameters from the controller and use it to the authorization handler?

In the old .NET I can get the parameters from `HttpContext` request param like this:

```
var eventId = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Params["id"];
```

I am not sure how can I achieved it in .net core

```
public class HasAdminRoleFromAnySiteRequirement : AuthorizationHandler<HasAdminRoleFromAnySiteRequirement>, IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public HasAdminRoleFromAnySiteRequirement()
    {

    }

    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
        HasAdminRoleFromAnySiteRequirement requirement)
    {   

    //need to call get param from controller to used in the validation
    // something like this 
    //var eventId = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Params["id"];
   // I tried the suggestion below but I can't get the parameter from routedata
   // var mvcContext = context.Resource as     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.AuthorizationFilterContext;            

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that already but upon checking, HttpContext is null

Comment: Could you post code what you tried?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In your handler you can do the following

```cs
var mvcContext = context.Resource as 
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.AuthorizationFilterContext;

if (mvcContext != null)
{
    // Examine MVC specific things like routing data.
}
```

If you want parameter values then the authorize attribute pieces run before binding has taking place. Instead you would move to an imperative call, inside your controller. This is basically [resource based authorization](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/resourcebased.html), your parameter is a resource.

You would inject the authorization service into your controller;

```cs
public class DocumentController : Controller
{
    IAuthorizationService _authorizationService;

    public DocumentController(IAuthorizationService authorizationService)
    {
        _authorizationService = authorizationService;
    }
}
```

Then write your handler slightly differently;

```cs
public class DocumentAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<MyRequirement, Document>
{
    public override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
                                                MyRequirement requirement,
                                                Document resource)
    {
        // Validate the requirement against the resource and identity.

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

You can see this handler takes a document, this can be whatever you like, be it an integer for an ID, or some type of view model.

Then you have access to it inside your HandleRequirementAsync() method.

Finally, you'd call it from within your controller, once binding has taken place;

```cs
if (await authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(
    User, 
    document,     
    yourRequirement))
{
}
```

Comment: I tried this but I can't find the params in routedata

Comment: At the point at which authorization runs parameter binding has not taken place. You would have to manually parse, or check imperatively in your code by calling the AuthorizeAsync() method on the Authorize service. It really depends what you are needing parameter values for.

Comment: Sorry my bad, your answer is correct. Thank you for your help

Comment: I don't know if the .Net core has been updated but apparently the RouteData values can now be accessed. Is this true @blowdart?

Comment: The line `context.Resource as Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.AuthorizationFilterContext;` is no longer applicable on `2.0.0-preview1`.  I inject `IHttpContextAccessor` into my `AuthorizationHandler` and then `_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetRouteData()`.

Comment: @blowdart I've been searching the web for hours, watching your videos, reading everything and checking out the workshops - but finally it's spelled out so that even an idiot like me can understand it. Thanks!
This could (I think) be clarified in the official docs: how do I set up a policy like AgeOver18 thats not checked against a hardcoded number?

Comment: @steamrolla That's not true.  I am using it in my core 2.0 application right now! Unless they put it back in before the official release.

Comment: Doesn't this break the entire point of having policies? Why not just do all authentication in the controller instead of writing a handler just to be called from within the method

Comment: For anyone using dotnet 2.2 and above, @Tohid's answer below is now the far better solution.

Comment: Can I use @Tohid 's answer to access a bound parameter that is parsed from the body? I can't see how... ?

Answer (score 55):

In ASP.NET Core 3.0 with endpoint routing enabled, you can get a route parameter value like this:

```
public class MyRequirementHandler : AuthorizationHandler<MyRequirement>
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public MyRequirementHandler(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
       _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpContextAccessor));
    }

    protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, MyRequirement requirement)
    {
        var routeData = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetRouteData();

        var areaName = routeData?.Values["area"]?.ToString();
        var area = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(areaName) ? string.Empty : areaName;

        var controllerName = routeData?.Values["controller"]?.ToString();
        var controller = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(controllerName) ? string.Empty : controllerName;

        var actionName = routeData?.Values["action"]?.ToString();
        var action = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(actionName) ? string.Empty : actionName;

        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: This solved my issue thank you! Just to note, in order to achieve this you need to inject httpContextAccessor with:
services.AddTransient<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
in your startup.cs

Comment: @AllenRufolo, and how to add policy with instance of this handler in services.AddAuthorize(...)?

Comment: just in case anyone need query string: `_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.QueryString`

Comment: Any suggestions on unit testing such a handler? Mocking HttpContext seems quite hard to achieve for this purpose!

Answer (score 20):

In ASP.NET Core 2.2, you can get a route parameter value like this:

```
public class MyRequirementHandler : AuthorizationHandler<MyRequirement>
{
    protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, MyRequirement requirement)
    {
        var authContext = (AuthorizationFilterContext)context.Resource;
        var routeValueOfX = authContext.HttpContext.GetRouteValue("X");
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```

Comment: This is by far the best solution for 2.2 and above, @blowdart's approach is no longer needed.  Thanks

Comment: This would fail in the aspnetcore 3.0 endpoint wiring: context.Resource is not an AuthorizationFilterContext in this case. IMO the IHttpContextAccessor is a more robust solution.

Comment: @EricPatrick - haven't started developing with aspnetcore 3.0 yet. Just wonder how can we get any HTTP Header or Rout Value in an `AuthorizationHandler<>`? Should we always inject `IHttpContextAccessor`?

Comment: @Tohid yes, I recommend injecting the IHttpContextAccessor; you can then avoid assumptions about AuthorizationHandlerContext.Resource type ;-)

Comment: @Tohid, for getting routes in 3.x, you could do for instance: 

var routeEndpoint = (context.Resource as Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteEndpoint)?.RoutePattern;

var cont = routeEndpoint.Defaults["controller"];

var act = routeEndpoint.Defaults["action"];

Comment: Works great, thanks. How would you unit test this handler? I have been trying to mock the HttpContext but somehow I just cannot get a correct route data mocked!

Comment: @Vinod - did you try to mock `HttpContextAccessor` ?

Comment: @Tohid I have tried it. Problem isn't the HttpContextAccessor or HttpContext. We can mock them both. However, GetRouteValue (and GetRouteData) method on HttpContext is an extension method and hence cannot be setup to return any value for tests.

Comment: @Vinod - Are you missing an assembly reference in your test project? Somehow I need to see your unit test code and the error you get.

Comment: @Tohid could you check the question I have raised? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77704169/mocking-routedata-for-authorizationhandler-tests

Answer (score 6):

For future reference, starting .NET Core 5.0, the HttpContext is now passed instead, so you can do:

```
if (context.Resource is HttpContext httpContext)
{
   var value = httpContext.GetRouteValue("key");
}
```

Comment: Any suggestions on how you would unit test such a handler?

Answer (score 1):

For .Net 5.0 (If you are using .NET 3.0, 3.1 then it will be better) use following:

```
public class MyAuthorizationPolicyHandler : AuthorizationHandler<OperationAuthorizationRequirement>
{

    public MyAuthorizationPolicyHandler()
    {
    }

    protected async override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, OperationAuthorizationRequirement requirement)
    {
        var result = false;

        if (context.Resource is Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.DefaultHttpContext httpContext)
        {
            var endPoint = httpContext.GetEndpoint();
            if (endPoint != null)
            {
                var attributeClaims = endPoint.Metadata.OfType<MyAuthorizeAttribute>()
                //TODO: Add your logic here
            }

            if (result)
            {
                context.Succeed(requirement);
            }
        }
    }
```

Please refer to following related discussion: ["context.Resource as AuthorizationFilterContext" returning null in ASP.NET Core 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59197631/context-resource-as-authorizationfiltercontext-returning-null-in-asp-net-core)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work in .net 8:

```
var id = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Query.FirstOrDefault(q => q.Key == "id").Value;
```

Where _httpContextAccessor is an instance of IHttpContextAccessor

Answer (score -1):

You can access parameters directly from your handler pretty easily. Now, I'm sure if think works for earlier versions of core (you should update core anyway if you can), but in core 2.0 and beyond, you can cast the `context.Resource` to an `AuthorizationFilterContext` in the `HandleRequirementAsync` method like so

```
if(context.Resource is AuthorizationFilterContext mvcContext)
{
   //do stuff to the mvcContext
}
```

Then, you can access the parameters like this

```
var value = mvcContext.HttpContext.Request.Query[key].FirstOrDefault();
```

where `key` is the parameter name you are looking for.

Or you could parse the query string like this

```
var queryString = mvcContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString.ToString()
var foo = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString);   
var value = foo[key]
```

again, where `key` is the parameter name you are looking for.