# Issue with lifetime of injected service or authorization relying on the HTTP request accessor in .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, authorization, asp.net-core-3.1

Inspired by [this blog](https://damienbod.com/2019/12/02/using-http-request-routes-request-body-and-query-string-parameters-for-authorization-in-asp-net-core/) on how to use body, query string and (hopefully) headers in my security, I'm trying to implement [custom authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/iauthorizationpolicyprovider?view=aspnetcore-5.0) handler [like here](https://jakeydocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security/authorization/policies.html) with the extra twist of injecting HTTP context accessor [along with this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47809981/1525840).

```cs
internal class HeaderHandler : AuthorizationHandler<HeaderRequirement>
{
  private IHttpContextAccessor Accessor { get; }

  public HeaderHandler(IHttpContextAccessor accessor) 
    => Accessor = accessor;

  protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(
    AuthorizationHandlerContext context, 
    HeaderRequirement requirement)
  {
    HttpRequest request = Accessor.HttpContext.Request;
    context.Succeed(requirement);
    return Task.CompletedTask;
  }
}
```

The problem is that the injected accessor has a different lifetime scope than the handler it's being injected into. I'm getting the error below.

> System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed'

The internal messages state the following.

> InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.IAuthorizationService Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor' while attempting to activate 'DemoApi.HeaderHandler'.

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor' while attempting to activate 'DemoApi.HeaderHandler'.

I find the idea of performing security **inside** the action method bad practice. Instead, I want it to be carried out **prior** to entering it, by the protective logic in the attributes for authorization. Am I over-sensitive on that subject? I.e. - is it according to best practice to rely on the requirements embedded in every action method?

Naturally, I've tried [setting my custom authorization service as transient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59353442/1525840), as scoped and as singleton. The same result each time. SO I sense that the issue might be no exactly with how I wire it up in configuration (at least not only). Commenting out the injection in the constructor makes everything work as supposed to (except for the headers not being available, of course, which is the whole point of the approach).

I've found a [similar issue](https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/server/issues/541) but specifically considering GraphQL authorization.

Comment: Did you register httpcontextaccessor? `services.AddHttpContextAccessor();`

Comment: @abdusco I'm thinking a word rhyming with a bird named Donald and. also, a large transportation vehicle... You may very well post it as an answer to be accepted. It took me 30 minutes to formulate the question and 30 seconds to answer it. Un-quacking-believable...

Comment: FYI, it would have been much faster to just search: "asp.net core AuthorizationHandler httpcontext", which would have led to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47809437/how-to-access-current-httpcontext-in-asp-net-core-2-custom-policy-based-authoriz. I can mark this as duplicate if you want

Comment: Or even just Google the all/part of the error message. So "Unable to resolve service for type" will take you to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40900414/asp-net-core-dependency-injection-error-unable-to-resolve-service-for-type-whil which would likely have given you the answer.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I see your point and I'd like to - first - argue against it. If you afterwards find that my argument isn't sufficient, I won't object duping this question. Here it comes. I've made by-the-book research before starting the implementation. I've checked several sources for how-to. I googled the error message and followed up all the links I've found in about 8 hours of work. There will be others getting stuck the same way. Now, to the answer itself - it answers *how to do it*, which is contained in my links. The explicit question  *what else* isn't really apparent there. :)'

Comment: @DavidG I sense a bit of backwards engineering in combination with pre-existing experience on your side. I googled the error I've got as far I understood it. The two internal messages where that obvious to me as relevant (especially the one quoted by you, as it appears very general, at least to me). Also, answers you both so kindly link to **do indeed** contain the missing part. However, I'd claim that it's hard to realize what the magic line is, as it drowns in the big picture. It's easier t see it once I know what I'm missing. But then, it defeats the purpose. What's your take on it?

Comment: I don't think there's any backwards engineering going on. When I have an error, I will google it and try to make that search as generic as possible. In this case, for example, I only took the first part before it mentions any types specific to your code. You could have done the same with the other part of the error message (*Error while validating the service descriptor*) which would have taken you to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59328439/error-while-validating-the-service-descriptor-servicetype-inewsrepository-life). That gives you context for hunting down your solution.

Comment: Learning how to search for things (aka having good Google-fu) is a great skill to have as a developer.

Comment: @DavidG I totally agree. And I truly admire those with predisposition to develop such g-foo. After 15 years of professional development, I can safely vouch that there are quite a few brilliant minds out there. Just please keep in mind that "obvious" and "reasonable" are relative terms. We do our best and we do appreciate the patience of the better ones.    :)

Comment: Note that I never once said anything was obvious, just that it was easy to google if you use a few simple techniques.

Comment: @DavidG Well, "easy" is equally relative. I'm not saying that the simple search techniques are useless. On the contrary! My point was that this particular case was not easy **unless** one had specific info on what to look for. Like I mentioned earlier, I did see one of those posts and still failed to extract the crucial part. Once I had seen the hint, it became apparent. And I'm not sarcastic - I actually admire (and envy) those who find looking up stuff easy. We can't exclude the option of me being less giftet. I can only do hard work and try my best. And I'm happy you are there. Thanks.